# =LEN Function in Google Sheet not working corretly

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a column with lots of rows containing text. I want to **highlight cells with over an x-amount of characters**, but how? The code I'm using in combination with 'Conditional Formatting' is not working all the time. Sometimes it highlights text over the x amount and sometimes it doesn't, so there is something I'm doing wrong here. The x-amount in the example below is: 300.

[image: Conditional Formatting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may also need to lock it like:

```
=LEN(E$1:E$170)>300
```

Comment: That's even better! Thnx again :)

Answer (score 1):

Silly me... I found the answer myself. I need to put in the same range in the formula as well. Formula with the range E1:E170 needs to be: `=LEN(E1:E170)>300`